# How to invoke platform specific driver in host machine?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writing a dummy PHY driver as a LKM. This is a platform driver
and I can't call the driver probe since it depends on the compatible string.
How can I make my driver invoke probe in my host machine, which is running
Ubuntu 18.04, kernel version - 5.3.0-40-generic. My machine is X86. I am installing this phy driver on my X86 machine.

Here is my code:

```
static int phy_platform_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) { 
  struct custom_port_phy_platform_local *lp;
  int ret;
  printk(KERN_ALERT "abc..phy_platform_probe..Invoked\r\n");
  lp  = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev,sizeof(struct custom_port_phy_platform_local),GFP_KERNEL);
  if (!lp) {
      dev_err(&(pdev->dev),"Failed to allocatate platform_local\n");

        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, lp);
    lp->dev = &pdev->dev;
    ret = custom_port_phy_mdio_setup(lp, pdev->dev.of_node);
    if (ret < 0) {
      dev_err(&(pdev->dev),"Failed to setup MDIO bus\n");
      return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}
static int phy_platform_remove(struct platform_device *pdev) { 
  struct custom_port_phy_platform_local *lp = platform_get_drvdata(pdev);
  dev_info(&pdev->dev,"%s Enter\n",__func__);
  custom_port_phy_mdio_teardown(lp);
    return 0;
}
static struct phy_driver custom_phy_driver = {
  .phy_id = 0x00000002,
  .phy_id_mask = 0xffffffff,
  .name = "custom_port_phy",
};

static struct platform_driver custom_phy_platform_driver = {
 .probe = phy_platform_probe,
 .remove = phy_platform_remove,
 #if 1
 .driver = {
    .name = "custom_port_phy"
    .of_match_table = port_phy_of_match,
 }
 #endif
};

#if 1
/* Match table for of_platform binding */
static struct of_device_id port_phy_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "custom,custom-port-phy", },
    {},
};
#endif

static int __init phy_init(void)
{
   int ret = 0;
   printk(KERN_ALERT "abc >>> phy_driver_register started\r\n");
   ret = phy_driver_register(&custom_phy_driver, THIS_MODULE);
   printk(KERN_ALERT "abc >>> phy_driver_register END\r\n");
   if(ret < 0) {
       printk(KERN_ALERT "custom phy driver registration failed\r\n");
       return ret;
   }
   ret = platform_driver_register(&custom_phy_platform_driver);
   if(ret < 0) {
       phy_driver_unregister(&custom_phy_driver);
       printk("%s: Failed to register as Platform Driver\r\n", __func__);
       return ret;
   }
   return ret;
}

static void __exit phy_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("Goodbye phy_driver .\n");
    phy_driver_unregister(&custom_phy_driver);
    platform_driver_unregister(&custom_phy_platform_driver);
}
module_init(phy_init);
module_exit(phy_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

My code doesn't do probe since it can't find compatible flag.
How can I make it work on my host machine? I know I need dtb file. Even if
I have dtb file, how do I supply it and how to write it that way?

Comment: Insufficient information, e.g. architecture (I suspect x86), EFI or not the BIOS.

Comment: I have added the details, this is for X86 locally on the host computer running Ubuntu. The machine is intel

Comment: It's only half of what I put in my comment. I assume you have newer machine, so it boots from EFI. And your system is quite likely ACPI based.